# How do I my Program to stop Replicating if wrong input

Tags: c++

My program will repeat output: "You are currently on the 2 floor out of 5
The sum of the codes is: 7 and the product of the codes is: 12
Try again before he catches onto you!" 
Based on how many wrong characters are added how can I fix this? I have inserted the cin.clear and cin.ignore but it will repeat the part above.

i.e. if I type wasds it will repeat 5x. Any other notes are also appreciated.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int PlayerLevel = 0;
int MaxLevel = 5;

bool GamePlay ()
{

srand(time(NULL));

int PlayerGuessA, PlayerGuessB, PlayerGuessC;

int CodeA = rand() % PlayerLevel + PlayerLevel;
int CodeB = rand() % PlayerLevel + PlayerLevel;
int CodeC = rand() % PlayerLevel + PlayerLevel;

int SumofCodes = CodeA + CodeB + CodeC;
int ProductofCodes = CodeA * CodeB * CodeC;

    cout << "You are currently on the " << PlayerLevel << " floor out of 5" << endl;
    cout << "The sum of the codes is: " << SumofCodes << " and the product of the codes is: " << ProductofCodes << endl;

    cin >> PlayerGuessA >> PlayerGuessB >> PlayerGuessC;



    int PlayerProduct = PlayerGuessA * PlayerGuessB * PlayerGuessC;
    int PlayerSum = PlayerGuessA + PlayerGuessB + PlayerGuessC;

    if (PlayerProduct == ProductofCodes && SumofCodes == PlayerSum) {
        cout << "Great Job you got this!!!\n" << endl;
        ++PlayerLevel;
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        cout << "Try again before he catches onto you!\n" << endl;
        return false;
    }

}


int GameStart()
{
    string Introduction = "Welcome to your worst nightmare. You are trapped in a murderer's house. You are on the 5th floor and need to get to the first floor to escape.\n";
    string Instructions = "He has each door locked behind a security system that requires a 3 number code to disarm it.\nEnter the codes and move foward. Each level will the code will be harder to figure out.\n";
    string PlayerStart;

    cout << Introduction << endl;
    cout << Instructions << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to escape? Yes or No" << endl;

    cin >> PlayerStart;

    if (!(PlayerStart != "Yes" && PlayerStart != "yes")) {
        ++PlayerLevel;
    }
    return 0;
}



int main ()
{

if (PlayerLevel == 0) {
    GameStart();
    }
while (PlayerLevel <= MaxLevel) 
{
    bool bLevelComplete = GamePlay();
    cin.clear ();
    cin.ignore();
}

cout << "You Made it out! Now run before he finds out!" << endl;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try `cin.ignore(1000, '\n');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the type of the input doesn't match the type of the variable that it is being extracted to, cin sets the fail bit. Once this happens, all subsequent reads fail until the stream is reset. The offending characters are still left in the buffer, so that needs to be cleared out as well.
Your usage of `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` meant that the fail bit was getting reset, but only one offending character was being removed (`cin.ignore()` ignores one character by default). This is why you saw the output repeating x times for x erroneous characters.

You could do something like this:

```
while (PlayerLevel <= MaxLevel) 
{
    bool bLevelComplete = GamePlay();
    if (cin.fail())
    {
        //Input extraction failed, need to reset stream and clear buffer until newline
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton that really helped out a lot. Also thank you for explaining why.